# Migrating custom coded/developed php project to CAKE php framework

Tags: php, cakephp, code-migration

My client wants to Migrating their custom developed php project to cake php framework. But, as of now i have only a bit of knowledge in CAKE. can anyone please let me know where do i get started CAKE php. i have already installed CAKE in my system

Comment: Why not start at the beginning: http://book.cakephp.org/view/879/Beginning-With-CakePHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get started? Probably on the [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) website?

Seriously, watch some screencasts, download some example apps and mess around with them.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP has a sweet steep learning curve. I recommend to go with the new 1.3 version.

It is easy to start with the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/) and the [API documentation](http://api13.cakephp.org/). When in doubt, just look into the source code, it's all just PHP! Google should be also a good friend of yours. However CakePHP is "just" a programming framework, you must know PHP, ORM, MVC and similar concepts in advance.